# Building a chrome extension and I am getting an inline listener error even though there is no inline listener

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, event-handling

[image: Error Message from chrome portal]

I have been building this chrome extension and I keep getting this error even though the event listener is in the app.js file and not in the html file. How do I go about fixing this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please throw old errors in the trash.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. Just had to clear the errors in the console.

Comment: I think the moderators will close this question, so I recommend you delete it before then.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).